9 term long exact sequence
I would like to draw 9 term long exact sequence (for example, Poitou--Tate sequence).
The goal of my image is the following.

The code so far is,
 \documentclass[11pt,english]{smfart} \usepackage[OT2,T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[english]{babel} \usepackage{url,xspace, smfthm}
 %\usepackage{amsthm} \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
 \usepackage{mathtools} \usepackage{tikz} \usepackage{tikz-cd}
 \usepackage{enumitem} \usepackage{fancyhdr} % パッケージの追加
 
 \usepackage{fancyhdr} % パッケージの追加 \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} %
 余白を調整
 
 \usepackage{amsthm}
 
 \usetikzlibrary{cd,bbox,babel}
 \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amscd}
 
 $0\to A\to B\to C\to D &\ar[dr, swap ]&\to E&\ar[dr, swap ]F\to G\to G\to H\to I\to 0$.
 
 \end{document}

Edit:
I took a liberty and move your actual code from comment below my answer to here:
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small] 
0\rar   & H^0(G_S,M)\rar 
            & \prod_{v\in S}H^0(G_{K_v},M)\rar 
                & H^2(G_S,M')^*\rar 
                    & \ H^1(G_S,M)\drar[bend left=20] 
                        &   \\ 
        &   &   &   &   &   \prod'_{v\in S} H^1(G_{K_v},M)\dlar[bend left=20] \\ 
0       & H^0(G_s,M')^*\lar 
            & \lar \bigoplus_{v\in S} H^2(G_{K_v},M) 
                & \lar H^2(G_S,M) 
                    & \lar H^1(G_S,M')^* 
                        &   
\end{tikzcd} 

Testing it shows that diagram diagram become quite wide and consequently spill out of right text border. Is this your new problem?
Please, evaluate it.

To be honest, it doesn't look like you've tried to use amscd nor tikz-cd.  Could you give those a shot?

I tried to use 'swap', I edited my question.

Your edit didn't really help, because &\ar isn't valid in $...$.  Zarko's edit with your actual code is helpful, because it shows what you're trying to do.  And that led to an answer that you were able to use.  Next time, please post something like the code in the answers, with everything we need from \documentclass through \end{document} so that we can copy and paste to see what's going on.

I suggest three lines:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[sep=small]
% head
0\arrow[r] & 
%1
H^0(G_S,M)\arrow[r] &
%2
\displaystyle\prod_{v\in S}H^0(G_{K_v},M)\arrow[r] &
%3
H^2(G_S,M')^* \arrow[d,bend left,shift left=8] \\
 & 
%6
H^1(G_S,M')^* \arrow[d,bend right,shift right=10] &
%5
\displaystyle\sideset{}{'}\prod_{v\in S} H^1(G_{K_v},M) \arrow[l] &
%4
H^1(G_S,M) \arrow[l] \\
&
%7
H^2(G_S,M) \arrow[r] &
%8
\displaystyle\bigoplus_{v\in S} H^2(G_{K_v},M) \arrow[r] &
%9
H^0(G_s,M')^* \arrow[r] &
% tail
0
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}



Beautiful !! Thank you very much.

I would use tikz-cd package:
\documentclass[11pt,english]{smfart} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz,
           diagrams={>=Straight Barb}
           }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[sep=small]
0 \rar  & A\rar & B\rar & C\rar & D\drar    &         \\
        &       &       &       &           & E\dlar  \\
0       & I\lar & H\lar & G\lar & F\lar     &
    \end{tikzcd} 
\end{document}


or
\documentclass[11pt,english]{smfart} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz,
           diagrams={>=Straight Barb}
           }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[sep=small]
0 \rar  & A\rar & B\rar & C\rar & D\drar[bend left]&             \\
        &       &       &       &           & E\dlar[bend left]  \\
0       & I\lar & H\lar & G\lar & F\lar     &
    \end{tikzcd} 
 \end{document}


** Addendum:**
Now is a bit more clear, what is actually in your diagram. As I mentioned in your question, now is not entirely clear, what is your problem.
Your diagram can be a bit shrink with use sep=tiny and \small font size, or rearrange your diagram:
\documentclass[11pt,english]{smfart} 
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                              % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz,
           diagrams={>=Straight Barb}
           }

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
    
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny] 
0\rar   & H^0(G_S,M)\rar 
            & \prod_{v\in S}H^0(G_{K_v},M)\rar
                & H^2(G_S,M')^*\rar 
                    & \ H^1(G_S,M)\drar 4  
                        &   \\ 
        &   &   &   &   &   \prod'_{v\in S} H^1(G_{K_v},M)\dlar  \\ 
0       & H^0(G_s,M')^*\lar 
            & \lar \bigoplus_{v\in S} H^2(G_{K_v},M) 
                & \lar H^2(G_S,M) 
                    & \lar H^1(G_S,M')^* 
                        &   
\end{tikzcd} 
 \lipsum[66]    
    \[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, font=\small] 
0\rar   & H^0(G_S,M)\rar 
            & \prod_{v\in S}H^0(G_{K_v},M)\rar 
                & H^2(G_S,M')^*\rar 
                    & \ H^1(G_S,M)\dar
                            \\ 
        &   &   &   &   \prod'_{v\in S} H^1(G_{K_v},M)\dar  \\ 
0       & H^0(G_s,M')^*\lar 
            & \lar \bigoplus_{v\in S} H^2(G_{K_v},M) 
                & \lar H^2(G_S,M) 
                    & \lar H^1(G_S,M')^*              
\end{tikzcd} 
    \]
\end{document}


(red lines show page layout)
Another possibilities is to make text block area wider. For example by use of geometry  package.
Anyway, it is unclear, what result you expected.

Thank you very much ! When I make A,B,... into what I intended. the bended arrows are bit weird. How can I change the size of them ?

My code is , \begin{tikzcd}[sep=small]
0 \rar  &H^0(G_S,M)\rar &\prod_{v\in S}H^0(G_{K_v},M)\rar &H^2(G_S,M')^\rar & \ H^1(G_S,M)\drar&\
&       &       &       &           & \prod'{v\in S} H^1(G{K_v},M)\dlar  \
0       &H^0(G_s,M')^\lar&\lar \bigoplus_{v\in S} H^2(G_{K_v},M)
&\lar H^2(G_S,M)& \lar H^1(G_S,M')^*&
\end{tikzcd}

@BrauerManinobstruction, please edit your question and put your code from comment to it. Also show us, what you got and what is the problem. By this you will get bigger probability that people will see what actually is your problem
